# Ускорить код ищущий 10 самых популярных групп среди подписчиков заданной группы ВКонтакте

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, инспекция-кода

## Как ускорить данный код? В среднем работа занимает около 4 минут на группу в 300 человек. Мне кажется дело в занесении групп в словарь. Есть ли какой-то более рациональный способ сделать это?

Данный код берет всех подписчиков определенной группы (в данном случае fineline_official), затем у каждого подписчика проверяет в каких группах он состоит `groups = api.users.getSubscriptions(user_id = mid)['groups']`. Затем добавляет в словарь id этих групп. Если в словаре нет id какой-либо группы, то он добавляет ее туда `groups_dict[gid] = 1`. Если же id этой группы уже есть в словаре, то прибавляет 1 к значению ключа. На входе получаем группу (id), на выходе 10 самых популярных групп среди подписчиков данной группы

```
import vk

session = vk.Session(access_token='token') #VK token
api = vk.API(session)
group_id = 'fineline_official'  #group id
group_stat=api.groups.getMembers(group_id = group_id )  #Получаем участников группы
members_id = group_stat['users']
members_count = group_stat['count']
groups_dict = {}
if members_count <= 1000:
    for mid in members_id:
        try:
            groups = api.users.getSubscriptions(user_id = mid)['groups']
            groups_id = groups['items']
            for gid in groups_id:
                try:
                    groups_dict[gid]
                    groups_dict[gid] += 1
                except:
                    groups_dict[gid] = 1
        except:
            continue
else:
    print('>1000')
lst = []
for k in groups_dict.items():   #Добавление в список кортеж из id группы и кол-ва участников
    lst.append(k)
lst_sort = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])  #Сортировка по кол-ву участников
print (lst_sort)
lst1 = lst_sort[-10:]   #10 самых популярных
print(lst1)
```

Comment: Добейтесь того, чтобы меньше обращений к серверу было. Вообще пользуйтесь подручными инструментами. Да и задавать вопросы было бы неплохо научиться.

Comment: @0andriy Не знал как правильнее сформулировать вопрос. Про подручные средства не совсем понял. Вы имеете ввиду парсинг?

Comment: Чтобы найти узкое место. Вы даже домашнее задание не сделали... Я высказал версию, но у меня нет подтверждённых данных. Вам и карты в руки, как только найдёте узкое место, тогда можно предметно разговаривать. Вдруг у вас модем на 9600 бод?

Comment: @0andriy На каждого пользователя идет 1 запрос, с этим думаю ничего не поделать. Мне кажется дело в занесении групп в словарь

Comment: Думайте дальше ;) Всего хорошего, держитесь там!

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо) Возможно что-то решится

Comment: Нужно не думать, а измерять и искать узкое место

Comment: Немного переписал ваш код, поменял lib и обработку ошибок, отрабатывает за 110.2s:
http://pastebin.com/2ERqY46M

Comment: @jfs Добавил описание

Comment: @jfs Да, именно так. Вход группа - выход 10 самых популярных групп

Comment: @r4d1f Насколько вы хотите ускорить? (1 минута это медленно?) Где у вас узкое место? Сколько времени сетевые запросы занимают?  Уверены, что throttle со стороны ВКонтакте не включён? Где узкое место? Что происходит если сетевые запросы заменить на заглушки, которые сразу соответствующие данные возвращают? Что profiler говорит?

Comment: @jfs В python я явно новичек, даже не знал о таком. Отпишусь после профилирования

Comment: Кстати, код можно упростить (вне зависимости от скорости): `top10groups = collections.Counter(g.id for m in members(group) for g in groups(m.id)).most_common(10)`. Попробуйте ещё пул соединений (requests модуль) и группировать запросы (более одного подписчика за раз—25 за раз если верить ответу внизу).

Answer (score 1):

Отрывок из документации VK:

- Ограничения и рекомендации

  - 3.1. Частотные ограничения К методам API ВКонтакте (за исключением методов из секций secure и ads) можно обращаться не чаще 3 раз в
    секунду. Если логика Вашего приложения подразумевает вызов нескольких
    методов подряд, имеет смысл обратить внимание на метод execute. Он
    позволяет совершить до 25 обращений к разным методам в рамках одного
    запроса.

Comment: Это не  то. В моем коде самый частый запрос происходит в строке `groups = api.users.getSubscriptions(user_id = mid)['groups']`. Но чтобы до него дойти снова, нужно выполнить последующий цикл, который точно выполняется дольше 0.33 секунды

Comment: @r4d1f вы измерили хоть, сколько времени эта строка выполняется-то?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью execute можно реализовать вот так:

```
import vk
import math

token =""

session = vk.Session(access_token=token)
api = vk.API(session)

group_id = "fineline_official"
members = api.groups.getMembers(group_id=group_id, v="5.62")

# сколько проходов потребуется, если брать из списка по 25 элементов
# делим кол-во элемнтов на 25 и округляем в большую сторону
num_of_pass = math.ceil(members["count"] / 25)

groups_dict = dict()

for npass in range(num_of_pass):

    pass_users = list()

    # забираем из списка 25 элементов
    for i in range(npass * 25, npass * 25 + 25):
        if i < members["count"]:
            pass_users.append(str(members["items"][i]))

    # код, который мы будем передавать
    code = """var u = [""" + ','.join(pass_users) + """];
        var i = 0;
        var r = [];
        while(i < u.length)
        {
            r = r + API.groups.get({"user_id":u[i]});
            i = i + 1;
        }
        return r;"""

    users_groups = api.execute(code = code);
    print(users_groups)
    for gid in users_groups:
        try:
            groups_dict[gid] += 1
        except:
            groups_dict[gid] = 1
```